# how to solve the problem when emulating my flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

can anybody help me? I'm doing a project in android studio using flutter. every time I try to run my project the following message appears:

Resolving dependencies...
Note: intl is pinned to version 0.18.1 by flutter_localizations from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.

Because life_tree_mobile depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, intl 0.18.1 is required.
So, because life_tree_mobile depends on intl 0.18.0, version solving failed.

You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

- Try upgrading your constraint on intl: flutter pub add intl:^0.18.1

I'm desperate, I have no idea what to do

I tried to run the project in the emulator and I was hoping to see it visually, but I can't

Comment: Can you show your .yaml code?

Comment: Just update in your **pubspec.yaml** file the dependency `intl: ^0.18.0` to `intl: ^0.18.1` that is the min required.